# Google Apps Script to list all Google Classroom courses and put them in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-classroom

I am trying to create a Google Apps Script that will list all the Google Classroom courses that are active and archived, along with the ID, NAME, SECTION, and COURSESTATE. Everything works except that I have no idea how to fix the .getRange so that it will put all the information in the Google Spreadsheet. The error I get is "Incorrect range height, was 4 but should be 10". If I put the .getRange as simply "A1:D1", it will overwrite what is there for each Class until the script finishes, so I know the rest of the script works, but I can't figure out how to put the range so that all the Classes can be listed. What I have up to now is this:

```
function listCourses() {
var response = Classroom.Courses.list();
var courses = response.courses;
 if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
   var course = courses[i];
   var ids = course.id;
   var title = course.name;
   var sec = course.section;
   var state = course.courseState; 
   var arr1 = [];
   arr1.push(ids,title,sec,state); 
   var arr2 = [];
   while(arr1.length) arr2.push(arr1.splice(0,1));

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = s.getSheetByName('LISTS');

  for (var x=0; x<arr2.length; x++){   
  var newRow = sh.getLastRow() + 1; 

// Here in the .getRange is where it gives me the error. A new row should be added for each Class until all the Classes (with the information mentioned above) are listed. 

  sh.getRange(1, 1, newRow, arr2[0].length).setValues(arr2);   
  }

}}}
```

Comment: Try `sh.getRange(1,1,arr2.length,arr2[0].length).setValues(arr2)`.  Eliminate the last loop and load it all at one time starting with what ever row you wish to start width.  I assumed row 1.

Comment: This line only puts the last Class in the Spreadsheet. I tried with and without the loop. On top of that, it puts it in A1:A4, when I need the information by rows (A1:D1, A2:D2, etc.). I have no idea why, but now, if I put

for (var x=0; x<arr2.length; x++){ 
    sh.getRange("A1:A4").setValues(arr2);    
  } It will paste one class over another until the loop finishes.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: 
I don't use Classroom API much and I only have one class in it but this works for it.

```
function listCourses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('LISTS');
  var response = Classroom.Courses.list();
  var courses = response.courses;
  var arr=[];//You could put column headers in here
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    var ids = course.id;
    var title = course.name;
    var sec = course.section;
    var state = course.courseState;  
    arr.push([title,sec,state]); //you could also go sh.appendRow([title,sec,state]); here if you wish and avoid the use of the two dimensional array all together as suggested in the other answer.
  }
  sh.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jason. You could bypass the range issue by using append row. This will however mean manipulating the data so that each class's details is on one row. I prefer this approach because it is let prone to errors. Also it automatically finds the next empty row in the sheet, so you don't need to get the last row.

```
function appendRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // Try is added to catch failures on automated scripts
  try {
    sheet.appendRow(['cell1','cell2','cell3'])
  } catch (e){
    Logger.log(e)
    // Could send an email here to alert script failure
  }
  // In a loop
  var data = [['row 1 cell 1','row 1 cell 2'],['row 2 cell 1','row 2 cell 2 ']]
  data.forEach(function(item){
    sheet.appendRow(item)
  })
}
```

Comment: I have tried 4 ways with .appendRow, but with no results. I have tried 
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = s.getSheetByName('LISTS');
sh.appendRow(arr2);

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = s.getSheetByName('LISTS');
for (var x=0; x<arr2.length; x++){ 
sh.appendRow(arr2); }

Am I missing a range or something?

Comment: Sorry you had a hard time. I updated the function. Make sure your append arrays are flat. I also added a looped example.